# SpringBoot @RestController not accessible from outside docker container

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot, dockerfile, spring-restcontroller

tl;dr One RestController answers properly, the other doesn't, if run inside a Docker container.

The service has two APIs `alive`

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
public class AliveController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/alive", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> alive() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and `callcount`.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class CallController {

    private static int callCount = 0;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/callcount", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> callCount() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(++callCount, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

They are both run through docker-compose.

```
version: '2'

services:
  service:
    image: my/service
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```

`docker-machine ip` returns `192.168.99.100`.

`alive` returns an empty 200 response. As expected.

```
$ curl -i http://192.168.99.100:4000/alive
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 17:33:58 GMT
```

`callcount` should return a 200 response and a number that increases every time the API is called. Sadly it does not.

```
$ curl -i http://192.168.99.100:4000/callcount
HTTP/1.1 404
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 17:37:26 GMT

{"timestamp":1471887446871,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/callcount"}
```

Running the service locally provides the expected result.

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:4000/callcount
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2016 17:43:40 GMT

1
```

The maven-spotify plugin is used to create an image from the following `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM java:8

EXPOSE 4000

VOLUME /tmp
ADD service*.jar app.jar

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/33882286/1309035
# Without this, Java uses /dev/random to seed its SecureRandom class, which can cause Java code to block unexpectedly.
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","app.jar"]
```

I am using the latest Docker and Docker-Compose versions (downloaded them 22. August 2016).

**Solved**! See updates section below. Will finalize question when final answer ist found. - **Question**: Why is `callcount` not accessible from outside the Docker container?

Further attempts:

- `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)` - same result
- Global CORS configurations from [the spring docs](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).
- Merging the two methods into the AliveController.
- Deleted every container and image and docker built again from scratch.

**Udates**:

The `callcount` API is not registered by Spring. I added another `test` API to verify this which is also not accessible through curl. `alive` still works fine and shows up in the logs.

```
bash-3.2$ docker logs asmstack_service_1 | grep callcount
bash-3.2$ docker logs asmstack_service_1 | grep test
bash-3.2$ docker logs asmstack_service_1 | grep alive
2016-08-23 08:42:06.530  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/alive],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> de.bahr.asmstack.AliveController.alive()
```

---

I use JDK 1.8 locally (java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation).

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

**Differences between startup methods**

The `callcount` is properly registered when running the app out of IntelliJ and with `mvn spring-boot:run`. It does not get registered if run with

`java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar my-service.jar` or

`java -jar my-service.jar`. This should be the cause why it is not accessible from within the Docker container.

**Any idea why this is the case?** It worked like that in another project from late 2015.

Comment: When Spring starts up the logs will include all request mappings that are being exposed. Do you see the mapping for the `/callcount` when running it in Docker?

Comment: I do assume your app works fine. The issue is most likely the image being created. I suggest you run a fresh `mvn clean package` to create a new image and check with `docker images` if it was really freshly created. In general I didn't made good experiences with the spotify maven plugin, so usually just put a Dockerfile and call docker build after the mvn run.

Comment: @daniel.eichten I deleted every image and container and rebuilt docker from scratch. The issue persists.

Comment: How are you running the service locally where it works? Through Eclipse/IntelliJ or `mvn spring-boot:run`? There must be any difference causing the Controller not to be added or registered to your container. You can also try to `docker exec` a shell in your container and unzip the `jar` to double check that the class is in there. I also saw that you are using `java:8` image which is based on openjdk. Which JDK you are using locally?

Comment: @daniel.eichten there is indeed a difference between the IDE, `mvn` and `java`. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Did you also checked the container if the class is in the jar file in the container image?

Comment: @daniel.eichten I did not check that, as I already moved all APIs into one class.

Problem is fixed, thanks to you two! Maybe someone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with help from @daniel.eichten and @ShawnClark, but I don't understand *why* this fails/works. T

It was not a Docker problem, but with Spring.

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28023112/1309035) (question might be unrelated), I changed the Spring-Application from

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

to

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now all APIs are accessible as expected, also when running inside a Docker container.

Comment: This didn't worked for me