# Java ReST service running on docker but not accessible

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker

Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24 running on RHEL 7.

I created a simple ReST service using the [Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). The uber jar runs fine on my windows machine and I am able to access the service via the browser.

The Dockerfile:

```
# fetch basic image
FROM openjdk:latest

# application placed into /opt/app
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

# local application port
EXPOSE 8080
```

Now, I executed the following steps

1.Build the image

```
docker build --tag=java-rest
```

2.Run the container

```
docker run -p 18080:8080 -t -i java-rest
```

3.Check if the container is up

```
[root@l5341t ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS                     NAMES
38ec56c99135        java-rest           "bash"              About a minute ago   Up About a minute               0.0.0.0:18080->8080/tcp   infallible_yalow
```

4.Copy the jar file to the container

```
docker cp /localhome/ojoqcu/code/java/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar 38ec56c99135:/opt/app/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
```

5.Run the container and also the jar

```
docker run -p 18080:8080 -t -i java-rest
root@38ec56c99135:/opt/app# ls
gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
root@38ec56c99135:/opt/app#
root@38ec56c99135:/opt/app#
root@38ec56c99135:/opt/app# java -jar gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar
```

6.On the container, the application is running

```
root@38ec56c99135:/opt/app# ps -eaf
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 13:43 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root         8     1  0 13:47 pts/0    00:00:14 java -jar gs-rest-service-0.1.0.
root        54     0  0 14:16 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root        60    54  0 14:17 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -eaf
```

The responses:

1.From the same machine(RHEL 7)

```
[root@l5341t ~]# curl http://localhost:18080
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirection</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY><H1>Redirect</H1></BODY>
[root@l5341t ~]#



[root@l5341t ~]# curl http://0.0.0.0:18080
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (tcp_error)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
A communication error occurred: ""
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
[root@l5341t ~]#



[root@l5341t ~]# curl http://l5341t:18080
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Network Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big><strong></strong></big><BR>
</FONT>
<blockquote>
<TABLE border=0 cellPadding=1 width="80%">
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
<big>Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)</big>
<BR>
<BR>
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">
Your requested host "l5341t" could not be resolved by DNS.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica">

</FONT>
</TD></TR>
<TR><TD>
<FONT face="Helvetica" SIZE=2>
<BR>
For assistance, contact your network support team.
</FONT>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
[root@l5341t ~]#
[root@l5341t ~]#
```

2.From my local Windows machine's browser(I think it's still hitting the Spring Boot's embedded server but unsure!)

```
http://l5341t:18080/
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu May 24 14:13:44 UTC 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Comment: in the 2. docker with Spring is responding, but saying that you didn't configure any / path. Maybe the example REST has a @RequestMapping("/greeting") , so you should call http://l5341t:18080/greeting    . From the local RHEL 7 machine, instead, shouldn't you connect to 8080 instead of 18080?

Answer (score 0):

I ain't digging deeper in the Spring code(it works perfectly on WIndows/Linux machines but not in the container!) but it seems that the issue is really with the code and not the Docker config. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106526/1106134).